# Docker fails on Tinkerboard running Armbian, Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Keep getting this error when trying to run containers:

`
sudo docker run -d --name hello hello-world

b22653867370a24ab900fc077f50fc6b05bb6eb986906caee88250fc9e9f5433
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error setting cgroup config for procHooks process: bpf_prog_query(BPF_CGROUP_DEVICE) failed: function not implemented: unknown.`

`docker --version Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f`

`uname -a Linux tinkerboard 5.15.74-rockchip #22.08.6 SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 18 06:40:37 UTC 2022 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`

`lsb_release -a No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Release:    22.04 Codename:   jammy`

Comment: Anything using the Berkeley Packet Filter low-level networking library probably isn't going to run well in Docker, since Docker heavily manages a container's network environment.  What's actually in your image?

Comment: the one in my post here is dockers own container to test your installation. I don't really know what's in it but i figure it's pretty lightweight.  
my goal is getting home-assistants up and running. They have a tinkerboard image iv e managed to run before. but that was before i started using a ssd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by installing DietPi instead and using their software interface to download docker. Worked otb :)